# How to setup different prices for same product for magento 2 store view?

Tags: magento2, price, store-view, multiple

We are currently running one website, one store, two store views (languages) for example one default store and second create new store Magento 2 install.
But I want to save prices multiple store views I am not able to how to set it.
I have to set price scope to "Website" instead of global in below settings.

**Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Price**

Please help me how to set prices in multiple store views?

Comment: Have got any solution?

Comment: yes we have to set currency rate so automatically change price store wise

Comment: Using admin configuration?

Comment: yes @ChiragPatel

Answer (score 3):

Magento does not allow setting a per store price. You can do this on a per website basis follow below step.

To do so, you need to go to

1. > Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog
2. Then in the tab "Price", set price scope to Website instead of
   global.
3. On the product edit page, you can then set the scope on the upper
   left side to your website and then enter a per website price.

Magento does not allow setting a per store price. However, there are some extensions which will allow you a per store price [Multiple Store View Pricing](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-multi-store-pricing.html)

I hope it will help to you.

Comment: The bsscommerce Plugin is temporarily disabled due to lack of support/updates.