# Other Store View prices changed to default store price

Tags: magento2, multistore

I am running a Magento 2 store. It has one Default store for the main domain and the second store for the other location/language. I have different prices for same product across 2 stores.

Suddenly a day, I see the price on second store is showing as the price in default store. I checked the log files but nothing to find. Can someone advice what could cause this and how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Set prices for all Stores , Once all attributes set for default values then in left side select other store where you want to change price or title
Also you can see this [How to setup different prices for same product for magento 2 store view?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244985/how-to-setup-different-prices-for-same-product-for-magento-2-store-view)

Comment: I have setup the price, Setting up is no issue. I will mass update the price through csv and running the script for 2 different store. But I am surprised to see the price for second store is showing as defauklt store price.